# Node run functions Sync, waiting an external value before returning . Async/wait

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I am developing an Angular/Node app in this part  I trigger an external device to read an NFC card and shall send this info to angular. But node is returning the HTTP response before I get the NFC info.

**edit to clarify more some points**

**key.controller.js** Here is where i land in node.js after the user clicks in some button requesting a NFC Reader to read some card

```
exports.requestKeyCode = async (req, res) => {
  console.log('KeyController');

  keyHelper.requestKeyCode().then( data =>{
    console.log('Did I wait?')
    res.send(data);
  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
      message:
        err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving Role."
    });
  });

    
  }
```

**keyYHelper** In this helper there is some extra code structuring the telegram sent to the NFC reader to read a NFC card

```
 exports.requestKeyCode  = async function()  {
  
      console.log('Entered requestDeviceInfo')
      finalTelegram=newData.toString(16)+CHKS.toString(16);
      this.ft=finalTelegram;
  
      sendTelegramLoop(this.ft, 0).then( keyCode => {
        return  keyCode ;
      })


  }
```

Here is expect to keep sending the telegram to the NFC reader, until something is valid is read

```
 async function sendTelegramLoop(telgeram, i ) {
     
    setTimeout(() => {
        hasRead = false;
      
        global.comPort.write(telgeram, 'hex' ,function(err) {
          hasRead =  waitResponse().then(hasRead => {
            if (err) {
              return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message)
            }
            if (!hasRead){
              sendTelegramLoop(telgeram, i++);
            } else {
              console.log('enteredExitRoutine');
              return hasRead;
            } 
            } );                   
        }) 
    }, 50)
}
```

this is where I set the comPort to read mode and start to listen the telegrams sent by the NFC reader, and filter the valid response telegram.

```
    async function waitResponse() {
      
    console.log("waiting keyInfo");
    rcvTelegram =  global.comPort.read().toString('hex');
     
    if (rcvTelegram.startsWith('a40101001c0a000') && rcvTelegram.length===56){
        console.log("breaking telegram")
        keyInfo =  telegramHelper.breakTelegram(rcvTelegram) ;
        console.log('Key Read='+ keyInfo);
        return keyInfo;
    } 
      

}
```

Basically what happens is that after I send the command to my device to read the card, nodeJS is returning the HTTP request.

How can I force it to wait.

Comment: try using `Promise.all()`

Answer (score 0):

In `requestKeyCode()`, you need to either return the promise that is created in their or `await` it.  As it was, nothing was hooked up to the promise that the async function was returning so it would resolve before your `sendTelegraphLoop()` was actually done.

```
exports.requestKeyCode  = async function()  {
  
      console.log('Entered requestDeviceInfo')
      finalTelegram=newData.toString(16)+CHKS.toString(16);
      this.ft=finalTelegram;
  
      return sendTelegramLoop(this.ft, 0);
}
```

or with `await`:

```
exports.requestKeyCode  = async function()  {
  
      console.log('Entered requestDeviceInfo')
      finalTelegram=newData.toString(16)+CHKS.toString(16);
      this.ft=finalTelegram;
  
      let keyCode = await sendTelegramLoop(this.ft, 0);
      return keyCode;
}
```

Also, there is no reason to use this:

```
 .then(keyCode => {
     return keyCode;
 });
```

as it does nothing useful. It's just redundant code.  The promise you already had resolved to `keyCode` so there's no reason to make another promise with `.then()` that also resolves to `keyCode`.

---

Then `sendTelegramLoop()` also has problems.  You need to make sure that the promise your `async` function returns is hooked up to the asynchronous operations inside your function.  That is not happening in `sendTelegramLoop()`.

Here's a look at fixing `sendTelegramLoop()`:

```
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
}

global.comPost.writeP = util.Promisify(global.comPost.write);

async function sendTelegramLoop(telgeram, i ) {
    try {
        // is this delay a hack?  Why is it here
        await delay(50);
        hasRead = false;
        await global.comPort.writeP(telgeram, 'hex');
        hasRead = await waitResponse();
        if (!hasRead) {
            return sendTelegramLoop(telegeram, i++);
        } else {
            console.log('enteredExitRoutine');
            return hasRead;
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('Error on write: ', err.message)
        throw err;          // propagate error back to caller
    }
}
```

It looks troublesome to be using a higher-scoped variable like `hasRead` that is not declared locally.  In any case, this new implementation actually hooks all the asynchronous operations into the promise that the `async` function returns and returns a promise that resolves to the `hasRead` value and works recursively.

---

Also, `waitResponse` appears to not have anything asynchronous in it, so it can be just a regular function, not an `async` function.

Comment: First of all, thanks for having the time to help me!
The delay(50), is the timeout to send a new telegram to the NFC reader to attemp a new read. This is needed in order to make sure the system will be trying to read a card. Later will implement a timeout to skip this if nothing is read after 15seconds. Regarding the hasRead, it carries the keyCode, when I started it was to find out when we should stop this loop

Completing the waitResponse is where I breakdown the NFC reader response, in order to make sure its a valid one.

thansk again!